# Scala - value < is not a member of AnyVal

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Here is my code. I got a compile error at second case clause:

> Error:(92, 26) value < is not a member of AnyVal
>             case x if x._2 < 2 => "price under 2"

```
def tupleMatch: Unit = {
  val donut = Tuple2("Donut", 2.5)
  val plain = Tuple2("Plain", 1.0)
  val tuples = List(donut, plain)
  tuples.foreach { tuple => 
    val toPrint = tuple match {
      case ("Donut", price) => s"price of Donut is ${donut._2}"
      case (_, price) if price < 2 => "price under 2"
      case _ => "other"
    }
    println(toPrint)

  }
}
```

After I change

```
val plain = Tuple2("Plain", 1)
```

to

```
val plain = Tuple2("Plain", 1.0)
```

it finally works. 
It makes me confusing, I want to know why?

Answer (score 5):

That is because your tuples array is formed by two different types: `Tuple2[String, Int]` and `Tuple2[String, Double]`. These types are inferred by the compiler and the interfered type of tuples array is then `Tuple2[String, AnyVal]`. When you put a Double representation the compiler is capable of create the `Tuple2[String, Double]`.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the REPL:

```
scala> val donut = Tuple2("Donut", 2.5)
donut: (String, Double) = (Donut,2.5)

scala> val plain = Tuple2("Plain", 1.0)
plain: (String, Double) = (Plain,1.0)

scala> val tuples = List(donut, plain)
tuples: List[(String, Double)] = List((Donut,2.5), (Plain,1.0))
```

Because the two Tuples have the same type `(String, Double)`, the List is of type `List[(String, Double)]`. `<` is a valid function for Double.

When you define plain as Tuple2("Plain", 1), the second part of the two Tuples are of different types (`Int` vs `Double`) so the resulting List is `List[(String, AnyVal)]`:

```
scala> val donut = Tuple2("Donut", 2.5)
donut: (String, Double) = (Donut,2.5)

scala> val plain = Tuple2("Plain", 1)
plain: (String, Int) = (Plain,1)

scala> val tuples = List(donut, plain)
tuples: List[(String, AnyVal)] = List((Donut,2.5), (Plain,1))
```

... and `<` is not a valid function for `AnyVal`.

Answer (score 2):

It because of we cannot perform `<` (less than) operation on `AnyVal` type.

```
scala> val donut = Tuple2("Donut", 2.5)
donut: (String, Double) = (Donut,2.5)

scala> val plain = Tuple2("Plain", 1)  
plain: (String, Int) = (Plain,1)
```

As you can see above. When you define `Tuple2("Donut", 2.5)`, `2.5` is inferred to `Double` and in `Tuple2("Plain", 1)`, `1` is inferred as `Int` since you have not provided type explicitly.

Now, when you create list of these tuples, because of type inference list type will be `(String, AnyVal)`.

```
scala> val tuples = List(donut, plain)
tuples: List[(String, AnyVal)] = List((Donut,2.5), (Plain,1))
```

Now, when you are performing `case x if x._2 < 2` you are actually comparing `AnyVal` type to number i.e. `2`, which is not possible because compiler thinks that `x._2` is `AnyVal`(not number) and won't compile. Therefore, you are getting exception at compile time.

```
<console>:22: error: value < is not a member of AnyVal
                 case x if (x._2 < 2) => "price under 2"
```

In your second case, i.e. when you defined tuple as `Tuple2("Plain", 1.0)`, its number type is also inferred as `Double`.

```
scala> val donut = Tuple2("Donut", 2.5)
donut: (String, Double) = (Donut,2.5)

scala> val plain = Tuple2("Plain", 1.0)
plain: (String, Double) = (Plain,1.0)
```

And, when you create list of tuples, since both have same type i.e. `(String, Double)`, list will have type `List[(String, Double)]`.

```
scala> val tuples = List(donut, plain)
tuples: List[(String, Double)] = List((Donut,2.5), (Plain,1.0))
```

And `x._2 < 2` will compile correctly since you are invoking `<` in double (number).